# Java-Repositioning of object when timer increments

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame with two buttons. One of the buttons when clicked moves (btnMove) the other button(shape) from the present position to another.I am using a thread as a timer to count in seconds but each time the counter increments, the button moves back to its original position.

```
    public class FrameTh extends JFrame {

    class count extends Thread {

        public int p = 0;

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

                lblCounter.setText("Seconds: " + i);

            }
        }

    }
    count t1 = new count();
 private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     

        t1.start();


    }                                    

    private void btnMoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
shape.setLocation(23, 44);


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The core problem is you're fighting the layout management API, which when you call `setText` is causing the container to be invalidated and relayed out

You might consider using something like `JLayeredPane`, but remember, you become entirely responsible for the size and position of the component

The other problem you have is you're violating the single threaded nature of Swing, Swing is not thread safe, meaning you shouldn't update the ui from out of the Event Dispatching Thread.

To solve that particular problem you should use a Swing Timer instead of a thread, see [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after using the JLayeredPane and using the Swing Timer, I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Did you apply a layout manager to the JLayeredPaned? The of using it is not to use a layout manager, the other choice is to make your own